# Trying To Figure Out A Text Scroll Effect

Tags: javascript, dhtml, effect

I like an effect that I have seen on a web site and I have been paintstakingly sifting through their javascript and CSS to see how its done.  However, the site is Korean and to make it more difficult, I am not too well versed in javascript to begin with.

The site is:
http://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=nexearch&query=idolfix&sm=top_hty&fbm=1&ie=utf8

Has anyone ever seen the effect on the top right of the page where the page is updating the 10 links every few seconds - specifically the way the text scrolls in place?

Comment: whoa! neat effect.  Seems to be in the "keyword" scripts... needs unobfuscation though.... be easier to rebuild the effect.

Comment: Yea, I inadvertantly checked an http-referer that visited my site (the URL in my question) and that was the first think that struck me.  Its been weeks of going through that code.  I'm trying to learn this design stuff being more of a database guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a wrapper div that has `overflow: hidden`.

Then inside that div they have 2 divs with the current and the next value.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="current">
        foo
    </div>
    <div class="next">
        bar
    </div>
</div>
```

After the effect you just have to make the `.next` the `.current` one, and add a new `.next` value with AJAX.

At first, the `.next` div is *outside* the .wrapper (underneath actually), then they move it up.

The effect could easily be done with jQuery moving the two divs at the same time.

```
$('.current').animate({
    'top': '-1em'
});
$('.next').animate({
    'top': 0
});
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tusbar/GFZTE/

Comment: Nice! Do you know how they're getting that to update every 5 or so seconds?  Ajax maybe?

Comment: Well just a `setTimeout` every five seconds that does an AJAX request, then updates the divs.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am going to experiment now.  :-)